# ngForm variable coming as undefined in component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a form in angular , and used template driven approach to control it . Have used ngForm in the group , and tried to access form fields via name , but i get an error in the console referring - this.form is undefined .

My html looks like -

```
<form #createProjectForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
.....
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>NMC/ODA Project No</mat-label>
              <input name="nmcNumbber" matInput autocomplete="off" />
            </mat-form-field>
```

And in the component file -

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, Form } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-project-details-fields',
  templateUrl: './create-project-details-fields.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-project-details-fields.component.scss']
})
export class CreateProjectDetailsFieldsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @ViewChild('createProjectForm') createForm : NgForm;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFormStatus();
  }

getFormStatus(){
  this.createForm.controls['nmcNumbber'].disable();
}
```

But the console gives -

[image]

Can anyone help me out in this ? TIA

Comment: I changed it to ngAfterViewInit but stil i am facing an error -

Comment: I don't think this is a reliable way to create a form. I think you should look at official documentation on how to set up a template driven form. Or just maybe the code don't show all the component. https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#introduction-to-forms-in-angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is too early. You need `ngAfterContentInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`. The view is not created in `ngOnInit` and `@ViewChild('createProjectForm') createForm` isn't set, yet.

You can't use `controls` to disable elements in a template-driven form. The line

```
this.createForm.controls['nmcNumbber'].disable();
```

won't work. You could use a `disable` directive in your template.

```
<input name="nmcNumbber" matInput autocomplete="off" [disable]="true" />
```

That's the main difference between reactive forms and template-driven forms. In a template-driven form most of the logic is in the template/view and in a reactive form most of the logic is in the view-controller.

Comment: I tried ngAfterViewInit - It is now giving "this.createForm.controls.nmcNumbber is undefined"

Comment: @AnandSrivastava In a template-driven you connect the variables with your form elements. You need `ngModel` for the controls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . But the line - this.HexCodeSettingForm.controls['wireNumber'].setErrors(null); worked for me in Angular version 5 , the same way i did here . is there any reason of not working in Angular 11 ?

Comment: @AnandSrivastava We left the scope of this question. The question was why `this.createForm` is undefined in `ngOnInit`. It's answered by this answer. If you have another question you should ask a new question.